# what features did c get from c++?

Tags: c++, c, history, language-features

What features were added to c that were originally in c++?
When where they added and for what reason(what where the pro/con arguments)?
How do they differ in c as compared to c++?

Did the features originate in c++ or in another language?

examples(feel free to expand on):const,Function prototypes, implicit exit(0);

Comment: too broad to be discussed here. You may try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you may have better luck on Programmers rather than here...

Comment: but c has changed and some features have been backported to some extent.

Comment: But C was changed after seeing C++. `const` is a correct example from the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be useful to repeat the content of [Bjarne's paper](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/sibling_rivalry.pdf)

Comment: question: do you mean that my question can be fully answered by his paper or that the paper has some of the answers and you submit it as your answer?

Comment: That paper is probably as close as an answer you can get without interviewing involved people.  Remember Kernighan, Ritchie, Stroustrup and some other influential people were colleagues while both languages were still evolving rapidly.

Comment: What about the committees? After the initial language development were the language creators mostly responsible for most of the decisions made?

Comment: Committee members are part of the involved people :-) The available committee papers could also bring some light.  But mostly on more recent changes (say what is happening with threads and memory model).